# Double quote string replace in C#

Tags: c#

How to replace the below string in C#

Current:

```
"John K "GEN" Greg"
```

The Goal:

```
 "John K \"GEN\" Greg"
```

This is wrong because I'm not escaping it properly:

```
s = s.Replace(""","\"");
```

What is syntax for replacing quotes with \ (slash)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
s = s.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

or

```
s = s.Replace(@"""", @"\""");
```

In the first example the `"` has to be escaped with a backslash as it would otherwise end the string. Likewise, in the replacement string `\\` is needed to yield a single backslash by escaping the escape character.

In the second example verbatim string literals are used, they are written as `@"..."`. In those literals no escape sequences are recognized, allowing you to write strings that contain lots of backslashes in a much cleaner way (such as regular expressions). The only escape sequence that works there is `""` for a single `"`.

Answer (score 10):

You should use a double backslash:

```
s = s.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 8):

To remove ALL quotes from a string, try:

```
field.Value = Regex.Replace(field.Value, @"[\""]", "", RegexOptions.None);
```

What a pain trying to find this answer on the internet!

Comment: For some reason other answers didn't work for me, this did ! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`s = s.Replace("\"","\\\"");`

What are you escaping it for? If you're going to insert it into DB, consider using [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead. If you're going to use it in your HTML output, consider using some template engine that does it for yourself instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try: `var result = yourString.Replace("\"", "\\\"");`

Answer (score 1):

```
string MailFrom ="aaa@my.web.pk;\"PROMMS\" ccc@my.web.pk;";

string NewMailFrom = Regex.Replace(MailFrom, "\"[^\"]*\"", string.Empty);


Results

aaa@my.web.pk;ccc@my.web.pk;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question, but it is what I was looking for.