# In C#, how do I remove/replace the Double Quote inside another double quote within a comma delimited file?

Tags: c#, ssis

How do I remove or replace the Double Quote inside another double quote within a comma delimited file?

Following is the Text File content:

```
,"188 "F" ST #1",
```

I need to take off the double quote as below:

```
,"188 F ST #1",
```

I've been trying regex and other replace functions but cannot figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: One idea: loop through the entries of the csv, and use `String.Replace("\"", "");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double quote string replace in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393879/double-quote-string-replace-in-c-sharp)

Comment: How consistent is the formatting of your file?  For example, are there any spaces between the double quotes at the start or end of a value and the delimiting comma?

Comment: String.Replace("\"", ""); ---> this would remove all double quotes. I need to just replace --> "188 "F" ST #1", ---> with --> ,"188 F ST #1",.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is inherently under-specified, because it does not offer any way to distinguish quotes inside the quoted string from the quote that closes up the string.

One way to define this would be "all quotes not preceded and not followed by a comma", thus excluding `,"` and `",` sequences from consideration; you also need to preserve initial and trailing quotes.

Here is a regex to do it:

```
(?<!^|,)\"(?!$|,)
```

The quote character `\"` in the middle of the expression is surrounded by a negative look-behind on the left and a negative look-ahead on the right. The look-behind rejects quotes at the beginning of line and quotes that follow a comma. The look-ahead rejects quotes at the end of the line, and quotes followed by a comma.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/3jQOqQ/1)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Having issue constructing the Regex function: 
string input = text;
string pattern = (?< !^|,)\"(?!$|,);
string replace = "F"; Or ???
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);

Comment: @Syed Replace string is empty. You need to double the backslash in the pattern, or use verbatim string `@"(?<!^|,)\"(?!$|,)"`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string content = "words ,\"188 \"F\" ST #1\", more words";    
content =content.Replace("\"","");
content ="\"" + content.Replace(",","\",\"") + "\"";
```

This will wrap every comma with double quotes, it will also make sure the string starts and ends with a double quote

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jXhZkM)

Comment: Thanks for all of your posts!